# Heroku Postgresql pg:psql No Route to host

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

For now I am just trying to make the `heroku pg:psql` command work but my final purpose is to copy a database that I have on my computer (localhost) to the heroku postgresql database with the `pg:push` command.

For now when I simply try to access the database that I created on heroku, the `heroku pg:psql` command returns:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No route to host
    Is the server running on host "ec*-**-***-***-**.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" (**.***.***.**) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

postgresql.conf: (the lines are not commented)

```
listen_address ='*'
port = 5432
ssl = true
```

and `host all all **.***.***.** trust` in `pg_hba.conf`

I also tried to add rules to iptables in order to give access to the database from the host IP address provided by heroku.

I am on a Debian computer, how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

> psql: could not connect to server: No route to host

It means your PostgreSQL server is not starting up or is starting up on a different port.

Solutions you may try:

1. Check PostgreSQL service by command `ps -ef | grep Postgres`.
2. Check the port which PostgreSQL is listening to by command `netstat -tupln | grep Postgres`.
3. Make sure your server enables UDP port because PostgreSQL needs UDP port loopback for stats collector service.
4. Check the startup logs or database logs at pg_log about the problem.

Comment: Hope This Help Your Problem. GL

Comment: Thank you very much ! Actually I just found out that the problem was the firewall from the Internet connection I was on ... It would not accept the opening of the 5432 port ...